# Can I have a const member function that returns *this and works with non-constant objects?

Tags: c++

If I understand correctly, a member function that is not supposed to modify the object should be declared as `const` to let the users know about the guarantee. Now, what happens when that member function returns the reference to `*this`? For example:

```
class C{
public:
    C &f() const {return *this;}
};
```

Inside `C::f()`, `this` has the type `const C*`, so, the following will not compile:

```
int main() {
    C c; // non-constant object!
    c.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, we could provide a non-const version of `C::f()` to work on non-constant objects:

```
class C{
public:
    const C &f() const;
    C &f();
};
```

However, I do not believe that this is what we want. Note that the non-constant version does not change the object, but this promise to the users is not expressed... Am I missing something?

EDIT: Let me just summarize the question for clarity: `f()` does not modify the object on which it is called, so declaring it as `C &f();` without making it a `const` member is misleading. On the other hand, I do want to be able to call `f()` on non-const objects. How do I resolve this situation?

---

EDIT: It comes out from all the discussion that took place in the comments that the question was based on an incorrect understanding of what `const`ness of a function member implies. The correct understanding that I am taking away for myself is:

A member function that returns a non-const reference is intended to allow its users to change the object through the returned reference. Therefore, even though this function does not change the object by itself, there should be no inclination to declare it to be a `const` member!

Comment: You miss `const` in the original function declaration: " **const** C &f() const". Otherwise the function just doesn't make sense - const function returning object which is possible to modify

Comment: If you are returning a non-const reference, it implies that the function will be used to modify the object ... your options are `C &f()`, `C const &f() const`, or both.

Comment: I realize all this. But this is precisely my question: `f()` does not modify the object, so declaring it as `C &f()` without making it `const` is misleading. On the other way, I do want to be able to call `f()` on non-const objects!

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#logical-vs-physical-const

Comment: It's not misleading to have `C &f();`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Are you saying that the premise I stated at the beginning of the question (i.e. that a member function that is not supposed to modify the object should be declared as const to let the users know about the guarantee) is wrong?

Comment: "*I do want to be able to call f() on non-const objects. How do I resolve this situation?*" You just call `f()`. There's nothing stopping you from calling `const` methods on non-`const` objects.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg that's a guideline, not a law of the language. Your function IS supposed to be used to modify the object, otherwise you would not be wanting to return a non-const reference. There is no such "guarantee" with this function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why not? For example, I might have a non-const member `g()` of the same class and would like to enable the user to write `c.f().g()`. The fact that the user can invoke `g()` on the result of `f()` does not change the fact the `f()` by itself does not modify the object on which it is called.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg `C &f();` allows `c.f().g();`

Comment: Have you read the article posted by "wonko realtime" ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb It seems like there was a misunderstanding. You wrote: "Your function IS supposed to be used to modify the object, otherwise you would not be wanting to return a non-const reference." I am saying that I do NOT want  `f()` to modify the object (logically! the state of the object does not change after calling `f()`!) So, `f()` should be a const member. And still I want to enable the user to write `c.f().g()`.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg If `c.f().g()` modifies the object, then `f()` modifies it (logically). What you are saying is like saying drills don't drill holes - drill bits do

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the original function definition:

```
C &f() const {return *this;}
```

here you return a non-const reference to the const object, which would allow changing the const object and would be dangerous, therefore it's forbidden.

If you were to write it as

```
const C &f() const {return *this;}
```

would be callable from both const and non-const objects and would always return a const reference.

> Of course, we could provide a non-const version of C::f() to work on non-constant objects. However, I do not believe that this is what we want.

Probably that is exactly what you want. It's the only way to return a non-const reference when called on non-const objects and keep const correctness when calling it on const objects.

Comment: But suppose that I have a non-const member `g()` of the same class and the user wants to write `c.f().g()`. Can I enable this?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg no, a non-const function might modify it and isn't allowed to be called on the returned const reference. If `g()` doesn't modify it, it should probably be marked as const.

Comment: I realized that writing such a thing was forbidden if `f()` returns a const reference. However, I do not see anything wrong with the user's intent to invoke `f()` and `g()` in sequence on the same object and to have a guarantee that `f()` will not change the object. If there is nothing wrong with the user's intent, then it does not make sense that I cannot write my class in a way that will enable him to do it.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg you're too hung up on this "will not change the object" misconception. Try to forget that. Treat `const` method as meaning: can be called on a `const` object.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg it's only possible if you provide a const and non-const overload of the function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Your last comment gets right to the core of the problem. However, this is what it says in **Effective C++** (3rd ed.) on page 19 about const member functions: "Such member functions are important for two reasons. First, they make the interface of a class easier to understand. It's important to know which functions may modify an object and which may not. Second, they make it possible to work with const objects." The foundation of my question seems to be what Scott Meyers calls the primary reason for the existence of const member functions...

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg The problem is that whilst the function may not directly modify the object it would allow all the rest of your code to modify it through the returned reference. A function like that allowing any other code to modify an object is not const. Allowing other code to change an object is the same as changing your code directly in this case.